# Is it possible to override DataAnnotation attribute in .NET child class?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to override a DataAnnotation in the child class.

I have tried solutions by similar questions but I had limited success.

For example I have this class using the RangeAttribute

```
public class BaseViewModel 
{
    [Range(1, 99999999, ErrorMessageResourceName = "NotInRange9M", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Account))]
    public virtual decimal? Amount { get; set; }
}
```

and a child class:

```
public class ExtendedViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    internal decimal? _amount;

    [Range(1, 2000, ErrorMessageResourceName = "NotInRange2K", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Account))]
    public override decimal? Amount {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { _amount = value; }
    }
}
```

This example works, so the form with that uses the first object will give a client side validation error `"The amount must be between 1 and 999,999,999"` and the second one will say `"The amount must be between 1 and 2,000"`.

However if I want to have the child class without any validation at all:

```
public class ExtendedViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    internal decimal? _amount;

    public override decimal? Amount {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { _amount = value; }
    }
}
```

The form using this will still give the client side validation error `"The amount must be between 1 and 999,999,999"`, which it somehow inherits from the parent.

So we can override attributes but we can't get rid of them?
Is there another way?

I have also tried:

```
    new public decimal? Amount {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { _amount = value; }
    }
```

without success.

I had to work around this limitation but I want to understand this mechanism of Data Annotations so I can use them better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's an AttributeUsageAttribute... on Attributes classes.

For example, RangeAttribute looks like that

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property|AttributeTargets.Field|AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
```

One of the properties of AttributeUsageAttribute class is `Inherited`, which looks like that.

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets a Boolean value indicating whether the indicated attribute can
    //     be inherited by derived classes and overriding members.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if the attribute can be inherited by derived classes and overriding
    //     members; otherwise, false. The default is true.
    public bool Inherited { get; set; }
```

So as we've seen in Definition of `RangeAttribute`, `Inherited` property is not present in attribute.
So by default it's true, so attribute is inherited on overriding members.

Comment: Okay. How do we override the Inherited property to be false from within the child class?

Comment: You can't ! You'd have to create a custom attribute without inheritance.

Comment: Yeah but instead of decompiling the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RangeAttribute and copying all the code to a new Attribute with Inheritance=false, is it possible to extend it and switch the inheritance off?

Comment: @Nick but in this case, you would never inherit (on any child viewmodel). By the way, ViewModel inheritance is usually (my point of view, of course) a bad idea.

Comment: I want to use the RangeWithoutInheritance attribute only on one specific viewmodel

Comment: @Nick you may try to create a RangeWithoutInheritance , inheriting from RangeAttribute, and change Inherited property value. Not sure what will happen, to be honest ;) But is should work.

Comment: That didn't work :( Anyway, I will accept this as the answer because it seems infeasible